# How to use Thrift for message passing instead of RPC

Tags: c, .net-core, thrift

I know that Thrift is mainly aimed at full fledged client-server RPC but looking at the high level architecture it seems to me that it should be perfectly usable for bidirectional message passing as well.

What I would like to build on both ends (C, .NET Core) is following:

- Receive method: has reference to a socket, reads a full message, deserializes it, returns it
- Send method: has reference to a socket, serializes a given message, sends it to the wire.

I don't need threading servers, ... anything fancy. Essentially what I would love to get on top of what e.g. Protobuffs offers is out-of-box handling of buffering the whole message on receive end & generally message framing.

The problem is that I wasn't able to find any documentation on how to start building that using the current libs (I'm personally interested in .NET Core and C ones) APIs. The only thing I've found is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439317/thrift-for-bidirectional-messaging) but it doesn't really point to any resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thrift is an RPC- and serialization framework. That implies, that you also may use only the serialization part without RPC.

In combination with messaging systems the way to go is usually (roughly) as follows:

- serialize the message into a buffer
- send that buffer by whatever means you want
- the receiving end(s) deserialize(s) the buffer and process the data

If you plan to send different kinds of messages through the same channel, it may be a good idea to have a `union` envelope structure that contains all possible message bodies:

```
 struct MessageOne {
      // contents of this message type
 }

 struct MessageTwo {
      // contents of this message type
 }

 struct MessageThree {
      // contents of this message type
 }

 union MyMessageEnvelope {
      1: MessageOne   one
      2: MessageTwo   two
      3: MessageThree  three
      // easily extendable 
 }
```

To make it more elegant/reusable, one could also implement a custom transport to fit the needs and to encapsulate the logic a bit more. Thrift's modular structure makes it easy (the post linked by you also refers to that). There are a few samples in the `/contrib` folder of the source tree which may serve as a starting point.

If you have absolutely no idea where to start: Look at the tutorial and then at the test suite programs, both are great as a learning resource for Thrift starters.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes from doing something very similar:

- Clients using both C# (mix of .Net Core and Framework) and C++
- Using Thrift RPC as well as "plain messages" for pub/sub and general serialization

[The suggestion to put all messages in a top-level union](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52142091/10176713) is a good one as it will make it easier to de-serialize the messages.

Given the following thrift:

```
struct SubscribeRequest {
    1: string topic,
    2: string appid,
}

struct SubscribeReply {
    1: bool success,
    2: string topic,
}
service HttpService {
    HttpSDKDataTypes.SubscribeReply Subscribe(1: HttpSDKDataTypes.SubscribeRequest message),
}
```

`thrift -gen netcore` gives you:

```
  public async Task<Ruyi.SDK.Http.SubscribeReply> SubscribeAsync(Ruyi.SDK.Http.SubscribeRequest message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    await OutputProtocol.WriteMessageBeginAsync(new TMessage("Subscribe", TMessageType.Call, SeqId), cancellationToken);
```

The message identifier is included by the RPC call.  If you don't use the RPC call you get "raw" structs with no indication of how to deserialize them.

Putting them in a `union`:

```
union UnionExample {
    1: SubscribeRequest request,
    2: SubscribeReply reply,    
}
```

Takes care of that for you:

```
public async Task WriteAsync(TProtocol oprot, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  oprot.IncrementRecursionDepth();
  try
  {
    var struc = new TStruct("SubscribeRequest");
    await oprot.WriteStructBeginAsync(struc, cancellationToken);
    var field = new TField();
    if (Topic != null && __isset.topic)
    {
      field.Name = "topic";
      field.Type = TType.String;
      field.ID = 1;
```

After deserializing, they can be handled with:

```
    public void handler(UnionExample example)
    {
        if (example.__isset.request)
        {
            SubscribeRequest msg = example.request;
            // ...
        }
        else if (example.__isset.reply)
        {
            SubscribeReply msg = example.reply;
            // ...
        }
```

Check the options available in the generators.  `thrift -gen "csharp:union,async"` let's you use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements):

```
   public void handler(UnionExample example)
    {
        switch (example.Data)
        {
            case SubscribeRequest msg:
                //...
            case SubscribeReply msg:
                //...
```

Unfortunately the `netcore` generator doesn't do this in 0.11.0.

The thrift github repository has [examples of serializing into memory](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/csharp/test/JSON/Program.cs#L41) (rather than using RPC).  In general it's similar to:

```
Stream stm = new MemoryStream();
TTransport trans = new TStreamTransport(null, stm);
TProtocol prot = new TJSONProtocol(trans);
```

If you're going to be creating lots and lots of `MemoryStream` instances, take a look at [`Microsoft.IO.RecycableMemoryStream`](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2015/02/06/announcing-microsoft-io-recycablememorystream/).

Using a custom protocol/transport will simplify the process of sending a message as it will handle the boilerplate (and avoid extra objects of first serializing to memory then whatever you do with it).  The [thrift `contrib/` folder](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/contrib) has been mentioned. 
 [Here's our C# example](https://rendered-obsolete.github.io/2018/09/07/zeromq-thrift.html) of using Thrift over ZeroMQ.

A final note.  If you are going to use the RPC functionality at all, write your service methods with a single struct parameter.  Meaning:

```
service HttpService {
    // Do this
    string Subscribe(1: SubscribeRequest message),
    // Not this
    string Subscribe(1: string topic, 2: string appid,),
}
```

It will make it easier to get rid of the RPC and/or reuse the message.